# Formula for Processor Affinity Mask (IIS)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, central-processing-unit

I have a 24 cores/ 48 GB RAM server machine on which I want to set processor affinity for worker process to last 12 cores through IIS Advance settings, is there any formula, i don't want to set affinity through task manager as this pool is recycled quite often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/cpu

> **smpProcessorAffinityMask**
>   Optional uint attribute.
>
> Specifies the hexadecimal processor mask for multi-processor
>   computers, which indicates to which CPU the worker processes in an
>   application pool should be bound. Before this property takes effect,
>   the smpAffinitized attribute must be set to true for the application
>   pool.
>
> Note: On 64-bit computers, the smpProcessorAffinityMask attribute
>   contains the low-order DWORD for the processor mask, and the
>   smpProcessorAffinityMask2 attribute contains the high-order DWORD for
>   the processor mask. On 32-bit computers, the smpProcessorAffinityMask2
>   attribute has no effect.
>
> If you set the value to 1 (which corresponds to 00000000000000001 in
>   binary), the worker processes in an application pool run on only the
>   first processor. If you set the value to 2 (which corresponds to
>   0000000000000010 in binary), the worker processes run on only the
>   second processor. If you set the value to 3 (which corresponds to
>   0000000000000011 in binary) the worker processes run on both the first
>   and second processors.
>
> Note: Do not set this property to 0. Doing so disables symmetric
>   multiprocessing (SMP) affinity and creates an error condition. This
>   means that processes running on one CPU will not remain affiliated
>   with that CPU throughout their lifetime.
>
> The default value is 4294967295.

First, set smpAffinitized to true.

Processor identification goes from right to left. Starts at processor 0.  To set the affinity to the last 12 processors:

```
0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000
```

Then you convert that to hex:

```
0x1FFE000
```

Comment: When I look at the `snmpProcessorAffinityMask` values within IIS ('Application Pools' -> Advanced Settings) they always seem to be in decimal rather than hexadecimal.  e.g. '4294967295' Yet the property description says that it's a hexadecimal mask.  Why is this?

Comment: So, If I left default value in smpprocessoraffinitymask '4294967295', and set smpAffinitized to True, the application pool will use all available processors ?

Answer (score 4):

I have made a chart for each NUMA node affinity. Hope someone could benefit from it.

[image]

Comment: How do you use this fine chart?

Comment: since is binary, you can sum the ones you want, for example: CPU1 + CPU4 == 2 + 16 = 18; binary is 10010; 12 in hex; I want CPU8 and CPU9, then 256 + 512 which means 1100000000 and in hex 300